How long should it take to write a book for children (early middle grade)?
I am writing a book for middle-grade children (as a first-time author) and I need some advice from other fellow writers on how long should I work on a novel.

Please ask only one question at a time. I have deleted the other three (or four) questions from your post. Please ask each of them separately. You can ask as many questions as you want.

While you might have a time frame that you strive to finish your novel at, you should always work at your own pace. I started an upper-middle grade novel with a plan to have it finished and publishing-ready in two months (I didn't understand the industry or editing at the time) and started on the second draft by that deadline. Then I had a deadline of eight more months, and a little over a year after I started, I've begun querying literary agents.
If you're Stephen King and only need two months to write your novel before publishing it, then great! But (and if you're a first-time author, this is more likely) you may need a lot more than that to draft, revise, edit, and proofread your novel. Have a goal or deadline for yourself, sure, but comparing yourself to others is useless, as everyone has a separate writing journey. I know that from experience.
Whether it takes a few months or a few years, write at your own pace. Don't rush it and publish a book that isn't at its best quality.

As long as it takes.
Physically writing down the words is the only one that can even be estimated.  After that, there's having the original idea, working out the details, revising as needed -- if you get three quarters through and realized that it simply doesn't work because you made the wrong decision in chapter three and have to massively rework, or even throw out all the subsequent ones, that will add a lot -- mastering the skills of writing a book, and many more are unpredictable.
Dedicating time to it will speed up the process but there's no predicting the length of time.

1
Middle Grade books are supposed to be between 25,000 and 75,000 words long. Professional writers of fiction write between 500 and 20,000 words per day. It should therefore take you between 150 and two days to write a Middle Grade novel. Research, character development, outlining etc. might add to that.
2
Successful writers of popular fiction write between one and two books per year. It should therefore take you between 6 and 12 months two finish one book, including planning and revisions.
3
If this is your first book, asking how long writing it should take is the wrong question. Writing is a complex task and you will have to figure out all its different parts as you go. When you do carpentry and you build your first cabinet, it will most likely take you multiple times as long as after many years of practice. Writing is like that. For your first book, the proper question is how to write, and once you know how to write the next step is practising what you have learned until you gain the routine that will allow you to write at a professional speed. Only then should you ask yourself if your writing is efficient enough and how you can speed it up.

The big question is how much time a day you have to write, the speed at which you draft, and your target word count. Then you have to take into account potential interruptions to your schedule, both planned and unplanned.
So you need to figure out the first two things. I keep track of my writing production with a spreadsheet and put down the date and the number of words for that day. When I start for a day, I record the number of words I start with, then I've got simple math at the end.
You'll need an average, because you're unlikely to work at the same pace every day. Some days you'll have distractions, and some days you'll spend time thinking about exactly what you want in that next scene.
So the important thing is sit down and write and keep writing until you've finished your book. Somewhere along the line you'll get the notion of when you'll finish as long as you keep steadily at it.
